# How to submit form data from one view to another using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to Laravel and I am trying to figure out how I can submit data from one view to another. I've tried to read some other similar questions on here and watch some videos on this, but I am still not able to get it. Basically I have 3 submit buttons, and the data that's being passed over is from a form. I set up a new route and a function in my controller, but I am getting the error: `Declaration of App\Http\Controllers\PagesController::CallAction() should be compatible with Illuminate\Routing\Controller::callAction($method, $parameters)`. However I think I am following the correct format.

Here is my web.php:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function() {
  // CallCenter page
 public function CallCenter() {
    return view('Pages.CallCenter');
 }

 Route::post(
  '/CallAction/', 'PagesController@CallAction'
 );

});

Auth::routes();
```

My PagesController:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PagesController extends Controller
{

    // CallCenter page
    public function CallCenter() {
        return view('Pages.CallCenter');
    }
    // CallAction page
    public function CallAction() {
      return view('Pages.CallAction');
    }

}
```

And the from:

```
 <form action="/CallAction" method="post">
        @csrf
            <table style="width:70%">
                <tr>
                    <td width="33%">Date<BR>
                        <?php
                            date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');
                            echo date('m/d/y');
                        ?>
                    </td>
                    <td width="33%">Time<BR>
                        <?php
                            date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');
                            echo date('h:i');
                        ?>
                    </td>
                    <td width="33%">Campus<BR>
                        <select name="campus">
                            <option disabled selected value>-- Campus --</option>
                            <option value="XXX1"></option>
                            <option value="XXX2"></option>
                            <option value="XXX3"></option>
                            <option value="XXX4"></option>
                            <option value="XXX5"></option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="33%">Extension<BR>
                        <input name="extension" type="text" size="15">
                    </td>
                    <td width="33%">Name<BR>
                        <input name="customerName" type="text" size="40">
                    </td>
                    <td width="33%">Email<BR>
                        <input name="customerEmail" type="text" size="50">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3">Description<BR>
                        <textarea name="description" rows="2" cols="125"></textarea>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="33%"><input type="submit" name="convert" value="Convert to Ticket"></td>
                    <td width="33%"><input type="submit" name="close" value="Close Issue"></td>
                    <td width="33%"><input type="submit" name="hold" value="Put Issue on Hold"></td>
            </table>
    </form>
```

Comment: Which version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: The latest version 5.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issue:**

The issue is that your Controller is extending `App\Http\Controllers\Controller` which in turn extends the abstract class `Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController`. This `BaseController` already has a method called `callAction()` defined like this:

```
public function callAction($method, $parameters)
{
    return call_user_func_array([$this, $method], $parameters);
}
```

So if you want to have a method called `callAction()` in your controller, you need to provide the same interface and accept a `$method` and a `$parameters` array.

**Solution:**

The quick solution would be to rename your controller method `CallAction()` to something that does not conflict with a method name on the parent classes ... maybe `CallMyAction()` then update your route file to match the new name.

So you're doing everything right, you just picked a method name that was already defined elsewhere in the framework.

Comment: It's always the small things haha. I was freaking out, thank you so much